# Sentence in simple present tense in a past tense aticle

Tags: tense

[New york time - Mirgants ...](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/11/25/world/americas/tijuana-mexico-border.html)

> The unrest in Tijuana **comes** amid broader discussions about how to
>   deal with the growing number of migrants fleeing poverty and violence
>   in Central America who are amassed at crossing points in Tijuana and
>   elsewhere along the border.

The main tense in this article is past.

> veered, fired ...

Why did this sentence come out as simple present tense?

Comment: First, it's awkward not having everything needed to understand a question in the question itself. (I had to go to the link to figure out what you were asking—because neither **veered** nor **fired** appears in the passage you quoted.) Tenses *can* be mixed without a problem. This can be done between paragraphs (in this case) and even within the same sentence, if done appropriately. Not mixing tenses is merely a rule of thumb—because it often results in something ungrammatical or strange—but it's not a necessity. There's nothing *inherently* ungrammatical about it.

Comment: @JasonBassford no "veered, fired", because I just don't want to put too many stuff in a question.

Comment: For example: I still *have* some of the cake that I *bought* last week.

Comment: @JasonBassford, I just want to know WHY. Why this particular sentence? If I wrote an article about the accident, can I randomly pick a sentence to write it as simply tense?

Comment: In this article, because the unrest is *still* happening. It's an event in the present. It would be far less meaningful (and somewhat untrue) to describe it as something that only happened in the past—making it sound as if things are now fine. *There* ***was*** *an accident but there* ***is*** *still unrest.*

Comment: @JasonBassford, OK, thank you. I know. "The unrest " doesn't not refer to the "unrest happened on Sunday afternoo.", but the general unrest at the border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For additional context, here are the two initial paragraphs from the New York Times [article](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/11/25/world/americas/tijuana-mexico-border.html):

> A peaceful march by Central American migrants waiting at the southwestern United States border veered out of control on Sunday afternoon, as hundreds of people tried to evade a Mexican police blockade and run toward a giant border crossing that leads into San Diego.
>
> In response, the United States Customs and Border Protection agency shut down the border crossing in both directions and fired tear gas to push back migrants from the border fence. The border was reopened later Sunday evening.

And to repeat the phrase in question (emphasis mine):

> The unrest in Tijuana **comes** amid broader discussions.

---

First, tenses *can* be mixed without a problem. This can be done between paragraphs (as in this case) and even within the same sentence, if done appropriately. Not mixing tenses is merely a rule of thumb—because it often results in something ungrammatical or strange—but it's not a necessity. There's nothing *inherently* ungrammatical about it.

For instance:

> I still **have** some of the cake that I **bought** last week.

---

In this case, although an incident took place in the past, and there *was* unrest in the past—it's also true that there still *is* unrest.

If the past tense had been used, the reporting would be both less meaningful and also somewhat misleading. It might be interpreted as implying that there is no longer any unrest and that things are now fine.

By using the present tense in this section, the ongoing unrest is being highlighted.